# Python 3: urlextract package, PermissionError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Windows 10 x64, with Python 3.6.1 x86.

I have this script from a few months ago which was working fine, but right now it gives me a weird error. The script is a simple one that extract URLs from tweets saved in .csv files.

This is the script:

```
import datetime
from urlextract import URLExtract

twitter_files_list = ['File1.csv', 'File2.csv', 'File3.csv']
input_path = my_path

# Find domain of URL
def find_domain(url):
    return url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0]

# Clean domain from useless chars
def clean_domain(domain):
    domain = domain.replace("[", "")
    domain = domain.replace("]", "")
    domain = domain.replace("\'", "")
    return domain

# Extract URLs from Tweets
def url_extract(filename):

    print('\n' + filename + ':')

    url_counter = 0

    url_file = open('extracted_urls/urls_' + filename, 'a')

    # Open file
    f = open(input_path + filename, "r", encoding="utf8")
    lines = f.readlines()

    # Search for contents of column "text"
    text = []
    for x in lines:
        text.append(x.split('\t')[4])

    # Close file
    f.close()

    extractor = URLExtract()

    for i in range(len(text)):
        try:
            if extractor.find_urls(text[i]):  # Check if URL exists
                url = extractor.find_urls(text[i])
                domain = find_domain(str(url))
                if not " " in domain:
                    url_file.write(str(clean_domain(domain)) + "\n")
                url_counter += 1
        except 'Not Found':
            continue

    url_file.close()


# Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('\nURL Characterization:\n')

    # Start timer
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Find the unique usernames for every file
    for twitter_file in twitter_files_list:
        print('Searching ' + str(twitter_file) + '...')
        url_extract(twitter_file)

    # End timer
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Print results
    print("\nProcess finished")
    print("Total time: " + str(end - start))
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Aventinus/url_analysis/url_extractor.py", line 77, in <module>
    url_extract(twitter_file)
  File "C:/Users/Aventinus/url_analysis/url_extractor.py", line 50, in url_extract
    extractor = URLExtract()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urlextract.py", line 65, in __init__
    if not self._download_tlds_list():
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urlextract.py", line 114, in _download_tlds_list
    with open(self._tld_list_path, 'w') as ftld:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\.tlds'
```

I have no idea how to interpret this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try run the script as administrator

Comment: Strangely, this solved the problem. Although I feel like this shouldn't be the case. Thank you.